# How Do I Remove All Roles From A User In Discord.Js?

Tags: discord.js

Im working on a bot that uses a command that can mute users, but I want it to first remove all roles from that user so that they cant modify their role or the server. I’ve seen this problem answered before on the website, but when I tried it didn’t work. I was wondering if anyone could provide some code that could help with this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Please try to make the code by yourself and come here with errors you may encounter.

Comment: I have tried several solutions, but none of them worked. I came here hoping that someone may have had a helpful solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Cursed's answer may work, there's a much simpler way to do this. Simply set the GuildMember's roles to an empty array

This code block is from the official DJS Docs

```
// Remove all the roles from a member
guildMember.roles.set([])
  .then(member => console.log(`Member roles is now of ${member.roles.cache.size} size`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

[View the docs for GuildMemberRoleManager#set()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=set)

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) which has property [roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) which is a collection of member [roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) where you can access all his roles and after just do a loop to remove all the roles.

```
GuildMember.roles.cache.forEach(role => GuildMember.roles.remove(role))
```